# What do they care about most? or What do they care about the most?

Tags: superlatives

> What do they care about most?

or

> What do they care about the most?

Are both correct?

Comment: Either way is fine.

Comment: Agreed.  Both are fine.  I'm not sure of which grammar rule explains this, though.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these are correct. If you remove 'the' it's better.

> What do they care about most?